# How to stop using weights on a tensorflow network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm using a simple two layer network, and instead of it being densely connected I wanted to "kill" 70% of the connections.

In my researches on the subject, i was told to multiply the weights variable by an array of zeros and ones, but how can i know that these weights aren't going to be updated, even if they where initially zero?

Comment: Can you provide some code? and, do you mean `Dropout` by "kill"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tf.nn.dropout` method.

Dropout randomly 'drops'(or 'kill') connection between nodes.

Say, you want to kill 70% of connections. then you can do like,

```
...
fc_0 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W_fc0) + b_fc0)
fc_0 = tf.nn.dropout(fc_0, keep_prob=0.3)
fc_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc_0, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
fc_1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc_1, keep_prob=0.3)
...
```